# Prevent parent route from re-mounting/rendering when moving from parent to nested route in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I have used create-react-app starter kit for React web application.

```
//Route.js 
<Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboardpage}>
  <Route path='editprofile' component={Editprofile} />
  <Route path='changepassword' component={changepassword} />
</Route>

//Dashboardpage.js
render() 
{
 return(
 ............
 ............
 <div className="center-block">
 <h4 className="text-center margin-top-10"><Link to="/dashboard  
 /editprofile">Edit Profile</Link></h4>
 </div>
 <div className="center-block">
 <h4 className="text-center margin-top-10"><Link to="/dashboard   
 /changepassword">Change Password</Link></h4>
 </div>
 {this.props.children}
 ............
 ............
)
}
```

On load of Dashboard the Dashboardpage gets rendered with some static content and with two links Edit Profile and Change Password. But on click of Edit Profile the path /dashboard/editprofile gets called but the Dashboardpage i.e the parent component again gets rendered with the child component i.e editprofile so flicker occurs.

The parent component i.e editprofile gets re-renders even if there is no change in that component. Please help me out how to avoid that flicker or avoid re-rendering of the parent component when no change occurs.